# How many time does the digit appear in the integer [Java]

Tags: java, algorithm

> Write a Java function count digits(int num); where num is a positive integer. The function counts how many times each of the digits 0..9 appears in num, and prints the results (see the following example below).
>   Example: Calling count digits(347213); will print the following: "The number 0 appaeared 0 times in 347213.... (same with 1, 2, 3).. **No helper/recursion allowed, only iteration**.

```
import java.Math.;

public int count-digits (int num){
int count = 0;
String numF = string.valueOf(num);
  // We get the number of digits by logs.
  for(int j=0; j <= 9; j++){ //loop for each digits
    for(int i=0; i < Math.floor(Math.log10(num)); i++){ //this loops checks each no.
      if(numF.charAt(j).equals(i)){
         count++;
      }
      return count;
      count=0;
    }      
  }
}
```

Two problems:

(1) How do I return the string alongside to it?

(2) Does this work? Is there a better solution?

Comment: this code doesn't even compile

Comment: convert your int to String and then use the following approach: [counting frequency of characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712587/counting-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: It says "no helper allowed" so i won't post an answer.

Comment: the return type is int what do u mean a string alongside to it and your count = 0 is not reachable! did u even tried this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void countDigits(int num) {      
    int count=0;
    String numF = String.valueOf(num);

    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
        count=0;
        for (i = 0; i <numF.length(); i++) {
            char c = numF.charAt(i);
            String number=String.valueOf(j);
            if (c == number.charAt(0)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number " + j + " appaeared " + count + " times in 347213");

    }
}
```

for this method you get an output like this

```
The number 0 appaeared 0 times in 347213
The number 1 appaeared 1 times in 347213
The number 2 appaeared 1 times in 347213
The number 3 appaeared 2 times in 347213
The number 4 appaeared 1 times in 347213
The number 5 appaeared 0 times in 347213
The number 6 appaeared 0 times in 347213
The number 7 appaeared 1 times in 347213
The number 8 appaeared 0 times in 347213
The number 9 appaeared 0 times in 347213
```

You cant compare chars with `equals`. Therefor you have need to have 2 chars you can compare with `==` and since you cant convert `int` to `char` u get a string with length of 1 and take first char.
I hope this i what you are looking for.

Comment: Instead of `for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)` I'd go with `for (char j = '0'; j <= '9'; j++)`.  No need to do `String number = String.valueOf(j)` then, as you can just do `if (c == j)`

Comment: well yeah seems to work just fine. Didn't know it was possible to iterate with char. thanks for the tip

Comment: Yep.  `char` is a primitive type (just a 16-bit signed integer), so you can do all the same mathematical operations on it.  Just need to remember that `'0' != 0` (note the quote marks).