# Method return in Java

Tags: java

I have written a code to find the frequency of each letter of the alphabet in a txt file in Java and write the results in another file .The problem is that frekuenca(String text) has an error cause it must return a result of type String.Can you think of a way to solve it? Thank you!

```
public class Frekuenca_File {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("teksti.txt"));
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("frekuenca.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String fjala = input.next();
            output.print(frekuenca(fjala));
        }
    }

    public static String frekuenca(String text) {
        int frekuenca = 0;
        for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < text.length() - 1; j++) {
                if (i == text.charAt(j)) {
                    frekuenca++;
                }
            }
            String result = "" + i + ":" + frekuenca;
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have it return an empty String at the end? (The method should never reach the end)

Comment: I believe there must be something wrong with the algorithm also cause I did what you said but it still wont print anything at the other file

Comment: Why do you even return the frequency as a `String`? Why not an `int[]` or a `Map<Character, Integer>` or `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: Well you have it return at the end of the inner `for` loop. Why have the outer for loop? It'll never have more than one iteration since you return `result`

Comment: how can i change the return? Cause the idea was the i would check all alphabet letters with the first for loop and with the second one I would check the characters of the words. If therewas a match the counter would go up. That's why i return at the end of the inner for loop cause I need a result for every letter of the alphabet

Comment: You probably want a variable `result` declared outside the outer `for` loop.  You can then append to it within the loop, and return it after the outer loop.

Comment: If you want a result for every letter of the alphabet then you should probably be using a `Map`

Comment: Can't use that cause we havent done that in class yet and we should only work with the knowledge we have so far

Comment: What have you been learning in class?

Comment: Methods,Class,Arrays,GUI

Comment: `for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'Z'; i++)` will perform exactly **zero** loops because `i`, set initially to `'a'`,  is already greater than `'Z'` before the first iteration.  You might want to have a look at an  [ASCII code chart](https://www.asciitable.com/) (also valid for Unicode values `'\u0000'` thru `'\u007f'`); lower-case letters are numerically greater than lower-case.  And not all the characters `A`..'z' are letters, either.

Comment: I changed the code to this but it still wont work.   `for (int i = 65; i <= 122; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<text.length()-1;j++) {
    if ((char)i == text.charAt(j)) {
     frekuenca++;
    }   `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a here's what I did:

```
static int[] counts = new int[26]; {{
       Arrays.fill(counts, 0);  //Fill the array with zeroes
}}
static String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";     

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String fjala = input.next();
            countLetters(fjala);
        }
        for(int i =0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            output.println(alph.charAt(i) + " : " + counts[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void countLetters(String text) {

        for (int i = 0; i < alph.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
                if (alph.charAt(i) == text.charAt(j)) {
                    counts[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Logic:

Create a static int array to keep track of how many times each letter occurs. Have a `String` with all the letters and the use `charAt()` to move through all the letters. At the end, print all the corresponding letters and letter counts to the file.

Let me know if you have any questions!

---

Input File:

```
aaaa
bb
cc
ddddd
eee
fff
j
ddd
```

Output File:

```
 a : 4
 b : 2
 c : 2
 d : 8
 e : 3
 f : 3
 g : 0
 h : 0
 i : 0
 j : 1
 k : 0
 l : 0
 m : 0
 n : 0
 o : 0
 p : 0
 q : 0
 r : 0
 s : 0
 t : 0
 u : 0
 v : 0
 w : 0
 x : 0
 y : 0
 z : 0
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can always return a null String object. However I would approach the problem differently. I would parse the text file into chars. Store the number of occurrences of the 26 letters in an array of size 26 (0 - 25). Index 0 is number of a's etc. Each char is an 8 bit number. For example a is 97. (Look up ASCII Table). so the index of the array to be incremented is the char (ASCII value) subtracted by 97. So a 97 - 97 is index 0. b is 98 - 97 is index 1.

Answer (score -1):

create a simple string function like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String output = make_string("tyrone", 5);
    System.out.println(output);     
}

public static String make_string(String string, int x) {
    String return_string = (string + ":" + x);
    return return_string;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

in the function frekuenca, in the for loop ....i="a"and i<"z" ,this causing error i is integer and comparing with character 
so simply do typecasting or use ascii values in for loop or you can use charAt() function:for (int i = (int)a; i <= (int)Z; i++)
char a='A'char z='Z'
when storing the result variable 'result' is string and i is an integer 
you cannot store integer in a string.....do typecasting of i first to character : String result = "" + (char)i + ":" + frekuenca;

see the link

[How to count frequency of characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712587/how-to-count-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-characters-frequencies-order-occurrence/

[Convert int to char in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984975/convert-int-to-char-in-jav)

Comment: It's not using `String` literals  `"a"` and `"Z"` (with double-quotes), but rather _char_ literals `'a'` and `'Z'` (with single quotes).  `char` values _are_ integers

Comment: I changed it to this but it still wont print to output file                                                 `for (int i = 65; i <= 122; i++) {
for (int j=0; j<text.length()-1;j++) {
if ((char)i == text.charAt(j)) {
frekuenca++;`

Comment: Sorry, this is entirely wrong.  The original code has `char` literals, not `String` literals.  And it's perfectly OK to compare `int` values with `char` values without any explicit typecasting, but possibly misleading.

Comment: Yeah but still it doesnt seem to work. This is the output 53:053:053:053:053:0

Comment: To avoid confusion between `char` and `int`, it might have been better to write `for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {` - note that the upper case letters come before the lower case ones.

Comment: Did you move the `return` to outside the outer loop, as I suggested in my comment under the question?