# Determine the number of frequencies of each character in a given paragraph

Tags: java

Determine the number of frequencies of each character in a given paragraph.

[image: this is the output that need to be achieve]

[image: this is the input]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    
    
    static void ASCII(String paragraf)
    {
        int l = paragraf.length();
        int konversi;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            konversi = paragraf.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(konversi);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String str = in.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("\t");
        ASCII(str);
    }
 
    
    
}
```

Comment: Use a HashMap to store the characters and their respective frequency counts.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @tgdavies i need to determine the number of frequencies of each character in a given paragraph. And the output need to be as shown on the picture number 1. picture number 2 is the input.

Comment: And what part of doing that do you have a question about?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712587/how-to-count-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap and store the frequency count for each character.

```
static void ASCII(String paragraf) {
    int l = paragraf.length();
    Map<Character, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        char ch = paragraf.charAt(i);
        freqMap.put(ch, freqMap.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1);
    }
    // freq count
    System.out.println(freqMap.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java 8's stream Collectors functionality, try this:

```java
public void ASCII(String paragraph) {

        Map<String, Long> freq = Arrays.asList(paragraph.split("")).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(freq.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void ASCII(String paragraph) {
    paragraph.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
            TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String paragraph =
        "Aleph null (also aleph naught or aleph ) is the smallest infinite number. It is the cardinality "
        + "(size) of the set of natural numbers (there are aleph null natural numbers). Georg Cantor "
        + "invented and named the concept. It is the first infinite number in a series of infinite cardinal "
        + "numbers. In fact, it is the size of any set which can be matched with the natural numbers.";
    ASCII(paragraph);
}
```

output:

```
 : 66
(: 3
): 3
,: 1
.: 5
A: 1
C: 1
G: 1
I: 3
a: 25
b: 7
c: 8
d: 6
e: 37
f: 9
g: 2
h: 17
i: 25
l: 16
m: 9
n: 30
o: 9
p: 5
r: 18
s: 18
t: 29
u: 12
v: 1
w: 2
y: 2
z: 2
```