# Converting Java String into Map<Character, Integer>

Tags: java, java-8

Given a String in Java, what is the Java 8 way of converting it into a `Map<Character, Integer` where the value of the key is the number of times a character occurs in the String?

Is this ideal or there are better methods available(Notice how in lambda, the data types are mentioned because as far as I understood, the compiler will give an error otherwise):

```
String s = "abcdaaffeebb";
var m2 = s.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i).
                collect(Collectors.
                        toMap((Character ch)->ch, (Character ch)->1,(oldV,newV)->oldV+newV));
        System.out.println(m2);
```

Output of the above snippet is:
`{a=3, b=3, c=1, d=1, e=2, f=2}`

Comment: You could use `Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())`. Though note that will give you a `Map<Character, Long>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712587/how-to-count-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 2):

[`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) with [`Collectors.counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) as the downstream function yields the desired result.

```java
s.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```