# How to convert stream of character to Map<Character, Integer>

Tags: java, java-8

I want the map to have key as `Character` and value as `Integer`, value represents the frequency of the character.

The below code won't compile because I am probably using the wrong signature for the `.toMap`

```
String s  = "zwdacb";

// Snippet to get a map
s.chars().map(i->(char)i).collect(Collectors.toMap(Character key->key,(Character k)->1,(Integer ov,Integer nv)->ov+nv));
```

Compiler gives this error:

```
Candidates for method call Collectors.toMap(Character key->key,(Character k)->1,(Integer ov,Integer nv)->ov+nv) are:  
  
Collector<Object, ?, Map<Object, Object>> toMap(Function<? super Object, ?>, Function<? super Object, ?>)   

Collector<Object, ?, Map<Object, Object>> toMap(Function<? super Object, ?>, Function<? super Object, ?>, BinaryOperator<Object>)   

Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K>, Function<? super T, ? extends U>, BinaryOperator<U>, Supplier<M>)
```

Comment: [The documentation of ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) actually has an example of this.

Comment: `Character key->key` is not proper lambda syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Collectors.counting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()), and wrap it in [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) to transform each Long value into an Integer value:

```
Map<Character, Integer> frequencies =
    s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue)));
```

Comment: thanks but I think this would be slower

Comment: @curiousengineer: why do you think that?  It isn't.

Comment: Because you are unwrapping the `Long` object into `Integer` again vs directly being able to get to `Integer`. The value part of the map

Comment: You’re unwrapping the Long once per Map entry, not as part of the counting process.  Any effect on performance is negligible.

Comment: @curiousengineer your approach is boxing *every* intermediate result into an `Integer` whereas this answer’s solution only boxes the final counts. The performance differences, if you’re able to measure them, will depend on the actual input string. If performance really matters for character frequency, you wouldn’t use a `Map<Character, Integer>` for this task in the first place.

Comment: @curiousengineer, you're correct, this would be slower.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *[groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector))* and *[counting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting())* methods.

```java
String s  = "zwdacb";
Map<Character, Long> m
    = s.chars()
       .mapToObj(x -> (char) x)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
```

Output

```
{a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, w=1, z=1}
```

Here is a relevant question and answer.
*[StackOverflow – How to count frequency of characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712587/how-to-count-frequency-of-characters-in-a-string)*

Comment: I like this even more than my own answer! +1

Comment: @CardinalSystem, I had to look it up, actually.  I don't use _streams_ often; I would have used a _loop_ here.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Use code points, not `char`.

```java
Map < Integer, Integer > frequencies =
        input
                .codePoints ( )                          // Generate an `IntStream` of `int` primitive values, one or more per character encountered in the input text. 
                .boxed ( )                               // Convert each `int` primitive into a `Integer` object.
                .collect (
                        Collectors.toMap (
                                Function.identity ( ) ,  // Code point.
                                ( Integer a ) -> 1 ,
                                Integer :: sum           // Increment the frequency count, the value for this entry in our Map. 
                        )
                );
```

### Code point

Unfortunately, the `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Example: try `"".length()`.

Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.

Here is an code point savvy version of the `Collectors.toMap` approach seen in the Answers [by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77325981/642706) and by [Cardinal System](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77325688/642706).

As the key in our map, we use [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) to represent each code point.

The [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) returned by [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) yields a series of `int` primitive values, one per code point found in the input string. We convert each code point from an `int` primitive to a `Integer` object as we need an object rather than a primitive to be a key. The `int` to `Integer` conversion is performed by the call to [`.boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()).

```java
String input = "zwdddaaaaacbb";
Map < Integer, Integer > frequencies =
        input
                .codePoints ( )                
                .boxed ( )
                .collect (
                        Collectors.toMap (
                                ( Integer codePoint ) -> codePoint ,
                                ( Integer a ) -> 1 ,
                                Integer :: sum
                        )
                );

System.out.println ( "frequencies = " + frequencies );
frequencies.forEach ( ( Integer codePoint , Integer count ) -> System.out.println ( Character.toString ( codePoint ) + " = " + count ) );
```

### `Function.identity`

That first argument to `toMap` is saying for every code point, just use that code point. A shorter way of doing that is [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()).

```java
String input = "zwdddaaaaacbb";
Map < Integer, Integer > frequencies =
        input
                .codePoints ( )                          // Generate an `IntStream` of `int` primitive values, one or more per character encountered in the input text. 
                .boxed ( )                               // Convert each `int` primitive into a `Integer` object.
                .collect (
                        Collectors.toMap (
                                Function.identity ( ) ,  // Code point.
                                ( Integer a ) -> 1 ,
                                Integer :: sum           // Increment the frequency count, the value for this entry in our Map. 
                        )
                );

System.out.println ( "frequencies = " + frequencies );
frequencies.forEach ( ( Integer codePoint , Integer count ) -> System.out.println ( Character.toString ( codePoint ) + " = " + count ) );
```

### Result

When run:

```
frequencies = {97=5, 98=2, 99=1, 100=3, 128567=1, 119=1, 122=1, 129436=2}
a = 5
b = 2
c = 1
d = 3
 = 1
w = 1
z = 1
 = 2
```

In contrast, if we changed `.codePoints()` to `.chars()`, we get incorrect results:

```
frequencies = {97=5, 98=2, 99=1, 100=3, 119=1, 56887=1, 122=1, 56732=2, 55357=1, 55358=2}
a = 5
b = 2
c = 1
d = 3
w = 1
? = 1
z = 1
? = 2
? = 1
? = 2
```

Comment: Borque, great reply, but I am unclear on the difference here between simply saying `chars()` vs `codePoints` to get the stream. Please help with that as well in your response

Comment: @curiousengineer I appended a chunk at the end of the Answer, substituting `.chars()` for `.codePoints()`. That code will get erroneous results for most characters, for those beyond the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Comment: @curiousengineer As noted in my Answer, [just try](https://ideone.com/QoICHe): `"".length()`. Compare to `"".codePoints().count()`. Avoid `char`.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the nuanced clarification. Many people know stuff, but are bad at explaining things. You have a knack for both

Comment: And now try with `"️‍"`…

Answer (score 1):

I would use utilize [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) which takes a `mergeFunction` parameter that you can use to calculate the frequencies. In order to use this approach, you need to map your int stream to a generic stream using [`IntStream.mapToObj(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

Here's an example:

```
String input = "aabbbcdd";
Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = input.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c, c -> 1, (t, u) -> t + u));
System.out.println(frequencies);
```

Output:

```
{a=2, b=3, c=1, d=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: .map() will return IntStream => should use mapToObject

Second: you are missing parentheses for: Character key->key

```
s.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i).collect(Collectors.toMap((Character key)->key,(Character k)->1,(Integer ov,Integer nv)->ov+nv));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a third-party library, you could use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) `CharAdapter` or `CodePointAdapter` classes, and create either a `CharBag` or `IntBag` to count the characters by simply calling `toBag` on either adapter. While this answer doesn't use Streams, the advantage here, aside from being more concise, is that there is no boxing of `char` as `Character` instances or `int` as `Integer` instances. Everything remains either as `char` or `int` primitive values.

But before you continue using chars or codePoints with Strings in Java, you should read this blog from Cay Horstmann: [Stop using char in Java. And Code Points.](https://horstmann.com/unblog/2023-10-03/index.html)

If you're still convinced you want to use chars or codePoints, here are some examples with Eclipse Collections.

Here's a char example.

```
@Test
public void chars()
{
    String input = "abacab";
    CharAdapter chars = Strings.asChars(input);
    CharBag counts = chars.toBag();

    MutableCharBag expected = CharBags.mutable.empty();
    expected.addOccurrences('a', 3);
    expected.addOccurrences('b', 2);
    expected.addOccurrences('c', 1);    
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, counts);

    CharAdapter output = Strings.toChars(counts.toSortedList().toArray());
    Assertions.assertEquals(Strings.asChars("aaabbc"), output);
}
```

Here's a code point example.

```
@Test
public void codePoints()
{
    // Using the example input from Basil Bourque's answer
    String input = "zwdddaaaaacbb";
    CodePointAdapter codePoints = Strings.asCodePoints(input);
    IntBag counts = codePoints.toBag();

    MutableIntBag expected = IntBags.mutable.empty();
    expected.addOccurrences(97, 5);
    expected.addOccurrences(98, 2);
    expected.addOccurrences(99, 1);
    expected.addOccurrences(100, 3);
    expected.addOccurrences(128567, 1);
    expected.addOccurrences(119, 1);
    expected.addOccurrences(122, 1);
    expected.addOccurrences(129436, 2);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, counts);

    CodePointAdapter output = Strings.toCodePoints(counts.toSortedList().toArray());
    Assertions.assertEquals(Strings.asCodePoints("aaaaabbcdddwz"), output);
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain Java:

```java
public static Map<Character, Long> histogram(String str) {
    Map<Character, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        map.put(ch, map.getOrDefault(ch, 0L) + 1);
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Using Stream:

```java
public static Map<Character, Long> histogram(String str) {
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
            .mapToObj(str::charAt)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                           Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. Use `toMap` with a constant of `1` and then add one for each occurrence of the character.

```
String s = "zwdddaaaaacbb";
        Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = s.chars()
                .mapToObj(chr -> (char) chr)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(chr -> chr, a -> 1, Integer::sum));
        
frequencies.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
a=5
b=2
c=1
d=3
w=1
z=1
```

Note that if you collect to a `Map<Character,Long>` you can do it as follows:

```
Map<Character, Long> frequencies = s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
```

And streams are not always the most efficient solution.  Here is one that uses a loop and the `Map.merge` method.

```
Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
     frequencies.merge(Character.valueOf((char) c), 1, Integer::sum);
}
frequencies.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Yes, I also feel that many times they are just slower

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of producing the desired result:

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = Stream.of(s.split(""))
                                       .collect(groupingBy(
                                                  e -> Character.valueOf(e.charAt(0)), 
                                                  summingInt(e -> 1)
                                        ));
```

NOTE: Prior to Java version 8, use `s.split("(?!^)")` (to return a `String []` of individual characters as strings).

The `Stream#collect` method can take different grouping collectors as parameter. The one used here is [Collectors#groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector))

---

This also produces the result by using the `IntStream#collect` method:

```
Map<Character, Integer> result =
    s.chars()
         .collect(
             () -> new HashMap<>(),
             (m, k) -> m.merge((char) k, 1, (v, x) -> v + x),
             (m1, m2) -> m1.putAll(m2)
          );
```